# How to update firefox cfx addon with jpm addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have made Firefox addon using cfx and now firefox has change cfx to jpm.
Now I have updated my addon using jpm. But i couldn't update my older version to new version . Is there a way to do that??

```
//older package.json
 `{
  "name": "mysearch",
  "title": "My Search",
  "id": "jid1-muBPHCjQmjOfVw",
  "description": " This addon provides an advanced keyword-based search functionality through this extension",
  "author": "sameera",
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "version": "1.0"
}
//new package.json
{
  "title": "My Search",
  "name": "mysearch",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "id": "jid1-muBPHCjQmjOfVw@jetpack",
  "description": "This addon provides an advanced keyword-based search functionality through this extension",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "sameera",
  "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "keywords": [
    "jetpack"
  ]
}`
```

Comment: Please expand on 
"But i couldn't update new version to my older version"

Comment: i had upload a addon before octomber and now firefox said it isn't compatible with new browser. So i have change it with jpm. Now i want to update my addon. But it shoes me a error.              "Add-on ID doesn't match add-on"

Answer (score 1):

Just append `@jetpack` to the id that you have in the `package.json` of the cfx-built add-on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx_to_jpm

Comment: I have added it to package.json and while uploading it gives me an error message again. "Add-on ID doesn't match add-on"

Comment: please add both package.json files (the old and the new ones) to your question